# How to add conditional statement to a flame sensor?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

I wanted to output 'flame detected' or 'no flame detected' but I don't know how to implement this in a code. I've seen codes from google but they are using

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(17,GPIO.RISING, callback = mycallback, bouncetime = 600)
```

which only works when it is detecting flame.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are detecting a *rising* edge (the pin goes from low to high). A *falling* edge is the opposite so you could fire a separate callback with:

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING, callback=other_callback, bouncetime=600)
```

However, I'd suggest you use [GPIO Zero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/) instead of RPi.GPIO as you may find it more intuitive:

```
from gpiozero import InputDevice

sensor = InputDevice(17)

while True:
    sensor.wait_for_active()
    print("Fire!")
    sensor.wait_for_inactive()
    print("No fire")
```

You might find that the logic is reversed (says "fire" when there's no fire) in which case use `InputDevice(17, pull_up=True)`

Alternatively to the code above you could use `if sensor.is_active` or use the callbacks mechanism `sensor.when_activated = callback`. See the [gpiozero docs](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#inputdevice) for more info.